# Problem with controlling ESP32 using python

Tags: python

Does anyone know what went wrong with my code? I'm trying to use Python to control esp32cam but I don't know what went wrong.

Sorry, I'm not sure if I'm posting this correctly as it's my first time asking! This is my code.

I changed the code after Dr.Casual helped (thanks alot btw!) but I'm still having errors. Updated the code.

```
 import cv2 as cv
 import numpy as np
 import urllib.request


# change to your ESP32-CAM ip

 url = 'http://192.168.99.119/'       # hi or lo
 winName = 'CAM'
 cv.namedWindow("winName")

 while 1:
  imgResponse = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  imgNp = np.array(bytearray(imgResponse.read()), dtype=np.uint8)
  img = cv.imdecode(imgNp, -1)

 cv.imshow("winName", img)
 tecla = cv.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
 if tecla == 27:
    break


 cv.destroyALLWINDOWS()
```

Error codes are as follows

```
        Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/fangyaoting/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/TSET.py", line 10, in <module>
cv.namedWindow("winName")
AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'namedWindow'
```

Comment: Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Looks like your indents are messed up a bit, could it be that? I suggest you copy the relevant part of the code in the question together with a stack trace of the error.

Comment: There is a problem with your indentation, please check again! You should also post the code.

Comment: @Dr.Casual I've posted the error, not sure if I did it correctly. Thank you!

Comment: @raspiduino I've posted the code! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```py
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import urllib.request


# change to your ESP32-CAM ip

url = 'http://192.168.99.10/cam-lo.jpg'       #hi or lo
winName = 'CAM'
cv.namedWindow("winName")

while 1:
  imgResponse = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  imgNp=np.array(bytearray(imgResponse.read()),dtype=np.uint8)
  img=cv.imdecode(imgNp, -1)

  cv.imshow("winName",img)
  tecla = cv.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
  if tecla == 27:
    break


cv.destroyALLWINDOWS()
```

In python, indentation is really important :)

edit:
note that I've changed the following

```py
while 1:
  imgResponse = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  imgNp=np.array(bytearray(imgResponse.read()),dtype=np.uint8)
  img=cv.imdecode(imgNp, -1)
```

on indentation, spaces should always be 2 (or 4). You used 1, which results in a syntax error.

also indented this bit, since it seems like this should be part of the loop:

```py
  cv.imshow("winName",img)
  tecla = cv.waitKey(5) & 0xFF
  if tecla == 27:
    break
```

Comment: Sorry can I ask what changes you made in the indentation? As I'm not sure which part I went wrong. I also have another question, I'm still encountering the error "SyntaxError: 'break' outside loop." Do you know how I can fix that? Thanks alot and sorry for the trouble!

Comment: Yes, updated the sample. Another piece of code should also have been indented. Let me know if you have any more problems :) If this helped you, please consider marking my answer as the solution, this helps me out :)

Comment: Oh thanks alot! You're a lifesaver. Oh thanks alot! I still have three errors
1. This code is unreachable:18
2. Typo: In word 'tecla’:20
3. 'break' outside loop：22 (I already indented 4 spaces but I’m still getting the error)

Comment: Did you copy the exact piece of code? The indentation should be the same inside of a function as well (2 or 4 not both)

Comment: Took another look at the code and changed some more. you imported cv2 as cv, but kept using cv2. Changed to cv. Also your variable names contained some typos (these are case sensitive as well)

Comment: Hi Dr. Casual! Thanks for your help. I edited my code as per your suggestions but I'm still getting errors. I updated the question with my updated code so if you don't mind please help to take a look again. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, those are not really errors, but PEP8 warning. PEP8 is a range of python conventions/best pratices. It's telling you that it would prefer if you'd use a multiple of 4 spaces (4, 8, 16, ...) instead 2 as indent. I personally prefer 2 :) It's also telling you to add a newline (just an empty line) to the end of your script. The code should however run correctly. If not, pls contact me again :)

Comment: Ooh! Thanks a lot. I do have one final error (sorry for the trouble!!). I’ve edited my question, it’s the error that starts with trace back. Thanks!!

Comment: Took a look at the docs and it's `namedWindow` instead of `nameWindow`. Also it's not necessary to pass `cv.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE` since this seems to be the default value. Changed the answer accordingly. Let me know if you have any more problems.

Comment: Omg I’m really sorry for the barrage of questions, but I ran the code and a multitude of other errors occurred. I’m seriously sorry but if you have the time could you help to take a look? I added the errors to my question. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: That's only 1 error, telling you it doesn't find whatever it's looking for at 'http://192.168.99.117/cam-lo.jpg'. Is your esp32 running, connected to wifi and on that ip-adress?

Comment: Ohh thanks alot! I removed the cam-lo.jpg and it stopped showing the 404 error, but now there's another error. I updated my question!

Comment: Assertion failed: size.width>0 && size.height>0 telling you it received an image with a height of width of 0. Probably because no images are coming through somehow

Comment: Sorry I tried changing some stuffs but the attribute error keeps showing up. I already changed it to namedWindow but it doesn’t seem to work. Updated my question!